C# files unreadable after pushing to github. Encoding seems to be wrong. How would I get back to original?
I had an old project I was going to reference, I know originally it was on windows when I created, pushed to GitHub, I cloned it on a Mac, and added it to a different repo that I keep specifically for references, and deleted the original repo, pushed, awhile ago, and now when I've went to reference it , its all scrambled, it says binary if I check the encoding from the cli, so I can’t re-encode it to uff-8 without having a ‘from’ encoding it seems. I guess I can find similar-ish questions but no real solutions. or I am not searching for the right terms. 
